# Target DIV if contains other DIV

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

My setup:

```
<div class="floatleft">
  <div class="search">[..]</div>
</div>

<div class="floatleft">
  <div class="submit">[..]</div>
</div>
```

My problem: I want to target the `floatleft` if it contains `search`. Is this possible in CSS? I want to make the text-input of `search` 100% wide, which can only be done by stretching `floatleft` to 100% (don't blame me, it's code I can't change). However, if I just stretch `floatleft`, it'll also stretch the other one (with the submit button) to 100%, which I don't want.

I've looked into [Advanced CSS Selectors](http://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/Advanced_CSS_selectors), but `.floatleft > .search` targets `search` if it's in `floatleft`. I want to target `floatleft` when it contains `search`. Is there something in CSS that can select the parent DIV of a targeted DIV? Something like '.search < .floatleft > .floatleft` (if that makes sense)?

Comment: Not yet. We've to wait for implementation of CSS Selectors Level 4.

Comment: You can't check for example if `.floatleft` contains `.search`. But you can target the first `.floatleft` or any subsequent `.floatleft`. Will that help?

Comment: @SalmanA I might try that. Good idea!